# Scala | Folding in binary tree

Tags: scala, functional-programming, binary-tree

I implemented a `fold` method in my scala code. I can use it to determine the `size` and the `depth` of the tree.
Now I'd like to implement the methods `max` and `map` which should work like [here](https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/answers/src/main/scala/fpinscala/datastructures/Tree.scala).
The difference is, that the value is saved in the branch instead of the leaf.
Here's my code so far:

```
sealed trait Tree[+A] {
  def size(): Int = fold(this)(() => 1)((l, r, v) => 1 + l + r)

  def depth(): Int = fold(this)(() => 0)((left: Int, right: Int, v: A) => 1 + (left max right))

  def fold[X, B](t: Tree[X])(f: () => B)(g: (B, B, X) => B): B = t match {
    case Leaf() => f()
    case Branch(left, right, v) => g(fold(left)(f)(g), fold(right)(f)(g), v)
  }
}

case class Leaf[A]() extends Tree[A]

case class Branch[A](left: Tree[A], right: Tree[A], v: A) extends Tree[A]
```

Can anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you can put `fold` to companion object of `Tree` (since `fold` doesn't use `this` i.e. is "static").

Secondly, start with implementing `map` for your case

```
def map[A,B](t: Tree[A])(f: A => B): Tree[B] = t match {
  case Leaf() => ???_1
  case Branch(l, r, v) => ???_2 // here l, r are Tree[A]'s i.e. subtrees of t
}
```

looking how it's [implemented](https://github.com/fpinscala/fpinscala/blob/master/answers/src/main/scala/fpinscala/datastructures/Tree.scala#L35) for trees with values in leaves.

Then replace this implementation with the one using `fold`

```
def map[B](f: A => B): Tree[B] = 
  fold[A, Tree[B]](this)(() => ???_1_)((l: Tree[B], r: Tree[B], v: A) => ???_2_))
  // here l, r are Tree[B]'s i.e. results of map for subtrees
```

`???_1_` and `???_2_` are `???_1`, `???_2`, where you replace recursive call of `map` with `l`, `r`, which are results of the recursive call. So `???_1_` is exactly `???_1`.

Comment: Than you, `map` works now! :) Do you have an idea about `max`? I tried `def max: Int = fold[A, Tree[Int]](this)(() => Leaf())((l: Tree[Int], r: Tree[Int], v: Int) => v max l.max max r.max)`, but this does not work as `v` is now an Int instead of an A. `max` has to be defined only for Int.

Comment: @Lolo This can't be correct because the second type parameter in `fold` means return type. `map` returns `Tree[B]`, so it was `fold[A, Tree[B]]`, now `max` returns `A`. Standard way to define a method only for fixed type is to use implicits: `def max(implicit ev: A =:= Int): Int = ???`